# System.AggregateException One or more errors occurred. OAuth2Request Xamarin

Tags: c#, facebook, xamarin, oauth-2.0

I hava a application that uses Oauth2 with facebook and google, but the applications run the folow exception after user is loggin:

> One or more errors occurred.

My code is this:

```
               var request = new OAuth2Request("GET", new Uri("https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,picture,email"), null, e.Account);
            await request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
            {
                var fbUser = JObject.Parse(t.Result.GetResponseText());
                var id = fbUser["id"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                var name = fbUser["name"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                var email = fbUser["email"].ToString().Replace("\"", "");
                var conta = new Account { Username = name };
                conta.Properties.Add("email", email);
                AccountStore.Create(Context).Save(conta, "VejoSeries");
                App.SuccessfulLoginAction.Invoke();              
            });
```

and give me a exception after a long time.. someone can help me?

Comment: look at the InnerExceptions property to see what the root cause of the error is

Comment: What is the reason you are combining old and new Task patterns by using  `ContinueWith` on the same `Task` you call using `await`? Just replace `await request.GetResponseAsync().ContinueWith(t =>
` with `await request.GetResponseAsync();` and remove the bracelets.

Comment: ok, but it is the reason of bug?

Comment: I fix that, closing visual studio,uninstalling the app in my device and open visual studio again..